# Disable the submit button after sending

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a problem in a containing page commands to send, when I click the button (Send command) it may take a while, depending on the size of it. So I want to disable  "Send order" to prevent user to resend. 
Here is the aspx code button "send order"

```
<wuc: SexyButton ID = "btnEnvoyerCmd" runat = "server" CssClass = "nv_boutonRouge"      onclick = "BtnEnvoyerCmd_Click" OnClientClick = "ShowLoadingPanel ();" />
```

and the javascript showloadingPanel ()

```
ShowLoadingPanel function () {

        if (arguments.length == 0) {
         / / No arguments -> text normal loading 
         if (_aspxIsExists (LoadingPanel)) {
             LoadingPanel.Show (); 
         } 
     } 
     else {
         / / Argument -> loading text specified 
         if (_aspxIsExists (LoadingPanelCustomText)) {
             LoadingPanelCustomText.SetText (arguments [0]); 
             LoadingPanelCustomText.Show (); 
         } 

         } 
    }
```

So I need your help, do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `btnEnvoyerCmd.Disable`?

Answer (score 0):

On server side function you can do at function start

```
btnEnvoyerCmd.Enaled=false;
```

or you can do it on client side using this code

```
var button = document.getElementById('yourButton');
button.disabled = true;
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can disable it like this:

```
$('#btnEnvoyerCmd').addAttr('disabled','disabled')
```